# Recasting an array in C

Tags: c, embedded

I have an embedded application that is reading 16-bit signed audio data off an SD card via 8-bit reads with SPI, so a buffer of `uint8_t` that is 2x as long as the audio sample, and then forwarding it on via I2S, which wants that same data as 16-bit values, so a buffer of `int16_t`.  Since the data in the array is already the 16-bit values, but split into 8-bit boxes, I would want to now deal with the array as an array of `int16_t`.  Is this possible without having to copy the contents?  Here's an example:

```
uint8_t i2s_buffer[4096];

/* spi_read performs 8-bit reads, so it reads the first half (MSB)
 * of the 16-bit signed audio sample first, then reads the second
 * half (LSB)
 */
spi_read(i2s_buffer, sizeof(12s_buffer), address);

/* Now i2s register is 32-bit wide, so takes
 * 4 8-bit samples, 2 16-bit samples, etc
 * but the width is set to 16-bit signed since the audio sample
 * is 16-bit signed, so we want the system to think of the
 * values as 16-bit, thus forcing the LRCLK to tick every half-buffer.
 */
i2s_start( <<i2s_buffer but 16 bits at a time as int16_t>> , sizeof((int16_t*)i2s_buffer) / sizeof(int32_t));
```

Comment: Could you share some sample code?

Comment: Sounds like you should use a `union`.

Comment: @Lundin Hmmm how so?  Wouldn't the values be overwriting each other?  I'm adding some pseudo code to be more clear.

Comment: Maybe also take into account endianness. Reading an storing MSB then LSB sounds like you store the uint16_t as BigEndian/network-byte-order into the array. Is this what expected at the forwarding phase?

Comment: @ulix Yes, i2s expects big endian generally.

Answer (score 2):

In embedded context, some things go unpunished, as you are working in specific environment with specific compiler expecting specific results. Just make sure the buffer is properly aligned to the datatype your want to access it with and you should be fine.

```
_Alignas(uint16_t) uint8_t buffer[N];
spi_receive_data(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
invert_endianess_if_necessary((uint16_t*)buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(uint16_t));
i2c_forward_it((uint16_t*)buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(uint16_t));
```

But if the data stored in SD card are already in `uint16_t` format ("logically"), then you are effectively reading `uint16_t`, not `uint8_t`. And `uint8_t` is datatype with 8 bits - it is not a "byte" (semantically). To represent a "byte" in C use `char`, `signed char` or at best `unsigned char`. So you may just read the data to a proper container from the start:

```
uint16_t buffer[N];
spi_receive_data((unsigned char*)buffer, sizeof(buffer));
invert_endianess_if_necessary(buffer);
invert_endianess_if_necessary(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer));
i2c_forward_it(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer));
```

Comment: Major disagree on the semantic part. He knows what his byte length is. It's 8 bits. It's not whatever weird byte system the manufacturer used (EG, SHARC's use a 32 bit char). He wants an 8 bit unit.

Comment: Actually, the data he is interested in, seems to be uint16_t. The uint8_t is just used in the SPI SD-card interface. Whatever the I2S interface uses, I guess, it is still handling data as uint8*. The only thing to consider is endianess on both ends, and to convert. And if the I2S can handle two uint16_t transfers, that should not really be exposed to outside in a proper design, unless the data itself has a certain protocol in the device addressed by the I2S.